# How to create Django FormWizard for one Model?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formwizard

I have Django Model with many fields which user must fill. If I'll create one ModelForm for this Model it will be big enough for one form. I want to split it using FormWizard. I think it's possible first to create forms dynamically and then create FormWizard using them.

Is this good approach or is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it seems fine.

The approach for creating partial forms is written in the [docs.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

In short:

```
class PartialAuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'title')

class PartialAuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        exclude = ('birth_date',)
```

Dynamic way of doing this would be:

```
def gimme_my_form(field_tuple):
    class MyForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = field_tuple
    return MyForm
```

Eventually you can also parametrize the model this way.

Comment: Nope, I don't like that. It's not ok for my model, there would be at least 4 tabs each containing 10 (average) fields.

Comment: What is wrong with that? 

Please, specify what usage would you like. Then we can come up with a suiting approach.

Comment: OK I just realized you want a dynamic way, I edited my answer.